# Difference between "Entire Solution" and "Entire Solution ( Including External Items )" options when using Find in Files command in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

"Find and Replace" dialog in Visual Studio, invoked with "Find in Files" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and "Replace in Files" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) commands, have the familiar option "Look in:", which determines the scope of the search, e.g. "Current Document", "Current Project", "Entire Solution".

While most of the options are self-explanatory, I cannot understand the difference between "**Entire Solution**" and "**Entire Solution ( Including External Items )**" options (and the respective "**Current Project**" and "**Current Project ( Including External Items )**").